# Onsubmit, display alert and redirect to some page

Tags: javascript, html

On submitting a form, a "Thanks" `alert` has to appear and at the same time it should redirect to google page at back side. In the below code which I tried, already has some function defined(form_validation) in `onsubmit` attribute. I cannot touch that because it will affect the form validation function. How to achieve this?

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function fn()
    alert("Thanks");
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="TheForm" action="www.google.com" onsubmit="return form_validation(this)" method="post" id="registerToDownload"  class="registration">
    .
    .<!--fields-->
    .
    <input value="submit" type="submit" onclick="fn()">
</form>
```

Comment: `onclcik`? Is that actually in your code?

Comment: onclcik should be onclick

Comment: sorry it's a typo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
    <script>

    function fn() {
        if(form_validation()){
            alert("Thanks");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    </script>

    <form name="TheForm" action="www.google.com" method="post" id="registerToDownload"  class="registration">
    .
    .<!--fields-->
    .
    <input value="submit" type="submit" onclick="return fn()">
    </form>
```

Remove 'onsubmit' property from the form and call the validation function in your function 'fn()'. The property  `onclick="return fn()"` does the trick by not submitting the form when fn returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you onsubmit confirm?

```
<form name="TheForm" action="www.google.com" onsubmit="return form_validation(this); return confirm('Thanks!');" method="post" id="registerToDownload"  class="registration">
<!--fields-->
<input value="submit" type="submit">
</form>
</script>
```

onclick was wrong in your code also.

The alternative in form_validation is to return false if form not validated, and alert if form validated. But you will need to put that in onclick, rather than on submit